# Elastalert - Aggregation issue's

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, elastalert

I am using Elasticsearch and Elastalert to send simple alerts to my slack channel.

Everything was fine until I started using aggregation
and now it says that `alert_sent:false`.
I read some questions about aggregation not alerting. Is there a way to do it anyway ?

Cause when im using `--save-json FILENAME` option all related alerts are there!

But still I need to be able to send that alert, it used to work once i cant remember what i did but i received 1 alert containing 2 events on slack.